# Integrating Roxy Unit Tester in a TeamCity build

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity, marklogic

Marklogic's description of roxy reads:

> Roxy Unit Tester produces JUnit XML output so you can use it with your favorite continuous testing tool

Would anybody know how to actually integrate Roxy Unit Tester in a TeamCity build?

Specifically, I am looking for a way to invoke the execution of the unit tests from TeamCity and a way to retrieve the output of the unit tests. Ideally, being able to fail the build when the tests do not all pass successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although using `ml <environment> test` is also a perfectly valid solution, I took a slightly different approach:

It is possible to call directly the xquery module (i.e. default.xqy) which is running the tests at this address: `http://your-server-name:test-app-port-number/test/`

Looking at the code of the module, passing the value "run" in the parameter "func" will trigger the execution of the specified "suite" and return the result in the specified "format".

From there, I created a simple Power-Shell script which first invokes the "list" method to retrieve the list of deployed test suites

```
Function Get-Tests-List {
    Write-Host "Retrieving test list"
    $body = @{ 
        func="list" 
    }
    [xml]$tests = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $tests.NameTable;
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace('t','http://marklogic.com/roxy/test');
    $root = $tests.DocumentElement
    $root.SelectNodes("//t:suite", $nsmgr) | Select path
}
```

, then loops through this list to execute the tests and saves the results as JUnit xml files

```
$url = "http://xxxxx:8102/test/"
$headers = @{"Authorization"="Digest username=""xxxx"", realm=""public"", nonce="""", uri=""/test/"", response=""xxxxxxxxxxx"", opaque="""""}
$output_folder = "C:\DeploymentScripts\test-outputs\"

$suites = Get-Tests-List

foreach($suite in $suites) {
    $body = @{ 
        func="run" 
        format="junit" 
        runsuiteteardown = "true"
        runteardown = "true"
        suite=$suite.path
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body -OutFile ("{0}{1}.xml" -f $output_folder,$suite.path)
}
```

These files are then passed to the "XML report processing" Build Feature which takes care of reporting the test results and even failing the build if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Roxy's command-line interface (ml or ml.bat) can be used to run the unit tests form command line. The XML returned is in some standard format (jUnit or something) that can be parsed and used to determine how the tests performed.

We use the Roxy tests in conjunction with the ml command with Jenkins and stop our build process based on the results.

The (very thin) information of this feature can be found here:
https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Deployer

Basically:

```
> ml <environment> test
```

Then have a look at the output and see how this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

To Integrate with **[TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)** " my personal favorite CI build system --
I would use the "Command Line" Runner", choosing "Custom Script" and following David Ennis's advise.

To report Test results and build status, use the Team City "  [Service Message] interface.  [2](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)

Use "Flow ID"s to seperate components.
Use ["Test suite messages"](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingTests) for each test suite.  This can include capturing the output to display in a dashboard.

For each test you can generate a distinct result.

I have not used, but looks likely to work,  the ["XML Report Processing"](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/XML+Report+Processing)

```
The XML Report processing build feature allows using report files produced by an external tool in TeamCity. TeamCity will parse the specified files on the disk and report the results as the build results.
The report parsing can also be initiated from within the build via service messages.
XML Report Processing supports the following testing frameworks:
JUnit Ant task
Maven Surefire/Failsafe plugin
NUnit-Console XML reports
TRX reports (for MSTest 2005/2008/2010/2012/2013/2015 and VSTest 2012/2013/2015)
Google Test XML reports
XML output from CTest
```